# Creating pandas columns with for loop

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe created through the following chunk of code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        (13412339, '07/03/2022', '08/03/2022', '10/03/2022', 1),
        (13412343, '07/03/2022', '07/03/2022', '09/03/2022', 0),
        (13412489, '07/02/2022', '08/02/2022', '07/03/2022', 0),
    ],
    columns=['task_id', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'end_period', 'status']
                )

df = df.astype(dtype={'status' : bool})
df.start_date = pd.to_datetime(df.start_date)
df.end_date = pd.to_datetime(df.end_date)
df.end_period = pd.to_datetime(df.end_period)
```

[image]

What I need to do here is to calculate the difference in days between the **start_date** and **end_date** columns if the **status** column is *False*, else it should do the same but between **start_date** and **end_period** columns.

The code that I have implemented to calculate the days differences between the **start_date** and **end_date** columns is as follows:

```
new_frame = pd.DataFrame()

for row in range(df.shape[0]):
    #extract the row
    extracted_row = df.loc[row,:]
    #Calculates the date difference in days for each row in the loop
    diff = extracted_row['end_date'] - extracted_row['start_date']
    diff_days = diff.days

    #Iterate over these date differences and repeat the row for each full day 
    for i in range(diff_days+1):
        new_row = extracted_row.copy()
        new_row['date'] = new_row['start_date'] + dt.timedelta(days=i)
        new_row = new_row[['task_id','start_date','end_date',
                           'end_period','date','status']]
        #appends the rows created to new dataframe
        new_frame = new_frame.append(new_row)
        #Rearranges columns in the desired order
        new_frame = new_frame[['task_id','start_date','end_date','end_period','date','status']]
        #Changes data types
        new_frame = new_frame.astype(dtype={'task_id' : int,'status' : bool})
```

[image]

Then in order to calculate the differences if the **status** column is *False*, I did the following one:

```
new_frame1 = pd.DataFrame()
new_frame2 = pd.DataFrame()

for row in range(df.shape[0]):
    #In this iteration, status column should be equals True
    if df['status'] == False:
        #extract the row
        extracted_row_end = df.loc[row,:]
        #Calculates the date difference in days for each row in the loop
        diff1 = extracted_row_end['end_date'] - extracted_row_end['start_date']
        diff_days_end = diff1.days

        #Iterate over these date differences and repeat the row for each full day 
        for i in range(diff_days_end+1):
            new_row_end = extracted_row_end.copy()
            new_row_end['date'] = new_row_end['start_date'] + dt.timedelta(days=i)
            new_row_end = new_row_end[['task_id','start_date','end_date',
                                       'end_period','date','status']]
            #appends the rows created to new dataframe
            new_frame1 = new_frame1.append(new_row_end)
            #Rearranges columns in the desired order
            new_frame = new_frame[['task_id','start_date','end_date','end_period','date','status']]
            #Changes data types
            new_frame = new_frame.astype(dtype={'task_id' : int,'status' : bool})

        
    #In this iteration, status column should be equals False
    else:
        #extract the row
        extracted_row_period = df.loc[row,:]
        #Calculates the date difference in days for each row in the loop
        diff2 = extracted_row_period['end_period'] - extracted_row_period['start_date']
        diff_days_period = diff2.days
        
        #Iterate over these date differences and repeat the row for each full day 
        for i in range(diff_days_period+1):
            new_row_period = extracted_row_end.copy()
            new_row_period['date'] = new_row_period['start_date'] + dt.timedelta(days=i)
            new_row_period = new_row_period[['task_id','start_date','end_date',
                                       'end_period','date','status']]
            #appends the rows created to new dataframe
            new_frame2 = new_frame2.append(new_row_period)
            #Rearranges columns in the desired order
            new_frame = new_frame[['task_id','start_date','end_date','end_period','date','status']]
            #Changes data types
            new_frame = new_frame.astype(dtype={'task_id' : int,'status' : bool})
        
#Merges both dataframes
frames = [new_frame1,new_frame2]
df = pd.concat(frames)
```

Then it throws an error when starts the first for loop, here is where I should be asking help on how to calculate the difference in days between the **start_date** and **end_date** columns if the **status** column is *False*, else calculate it between **start_date** and **end_period** columns.

[image]

The complete error is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some part of your code did not work on my machine (so I just took the initial df from your first cell) - but when reading what you need, this is what I would do

```
import numpy as np
df['dayDiff']=np.where(df['status'],(df['end_period']-df['start_date']).dt.days,(df['end_date']-df['start_date']).dt.days)
df
```

As you already have booleand on df['status'], I would use that to the np.where condition , then either calculate the day difference `df['end_period']-df['start_date']).dt.days` when `True` either day difference `(df['end_date']-df['start_date']).dt.days` when False